# Python 3 ipykernel hangs on a particular line of code

Tags: jupyter-notebook, data-science, jupyter-irkernel

I tried training a Linear regression model using model.fit on jupyter notebook as usual but my kernel is not executing the particular line of code and no error message.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
dataset=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\USER\Downloads\melb_data.csv\melb_data.csv')
dataset.head()
col_to_use=['Suburb','Address','Rooms','Type','Price','Method','SellerG','Distance','Bedroom2','Car','Bathroom','Landsize','BuildingArea','CouncilArea','Regionname']
dataset=dataset[col_to_use]
dataset.head()

col_to_fill_zero=['CouncilArea','Car']
dataset[col_to_fill_zero]=dataset[col_to_fill_zero].fillna(0)

dataset=pd.get_dummies(dataset,drop_first=True
X=dataset.drop('Price', axis=1)
y=dataset['Price']
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=2)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model=LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

at this point it shows this [*] and doesn't execute.
I tried interrupting and restarting the kernel still not working

Comment: How about you add the code so we can check it out? We aren't mind readers. Also this * symbol shows that it is executing, just never finishing

Comment: OKAY. I did not know how to add code initially but I found my way around. Is this OK?

Comment: Did you try to wait it out? If your dataset is correct (which I suppose you checked) it needs time to calculate. [*] is an indicator that it is currently executing. I don't know how slow your PC is but Linear Regression doesn't take a lot of time

Comment: Thanks. I will run it again and wait it out

Answer (score 0):

How big is your dataset, maybe just testing only 10% or 20% of your data will help to check the code, and if you add `%time` at the beginning of the cell it shows the run time for that specific code

[image]